# Facebook like : Uncaught TypeError: Object #<an Object> has no method 'provide'

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have recently added the facebook like button, but the following code returns an error in chrome: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'provide'

```
<!-- Facebook -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: '121814204514513', status: true, cookie: true,
             xfbml: true});
  };
  (function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
      '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
  }());
</script>
<!-- Facebook -->
```

The like button works but the error is anoying, does anyone know how to solve that?

Thanks

Comment: I am also having this problem, did you ever find a solution?

Comment: not sure if it's related but you can try to use this as your html header: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"> 
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraph.org/schema/" lang="en_US">

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently got the same problem when I tried to inject http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js into Google Reader ( for this exciting Kynetx coding contest : http://code.kynetx.com/2011/04/26/250-to-build-kynetx-facebook-send-within-24hrs-ends-apr-27th/ ) . all.js starts with "if (!window.FB) window.FB = { ..." and declares the 'provide' method . In google reader the FB object was already present (dont know why or how it was created) so the code inside the if never got executed. The trick I used was to set FB to null before including "http://http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js" . Google Reader didn't complain. It might be a solution in your situation too. 
Update: you may need to set FB to null this way:

```
var head = $("head").get(0);  // using jquery
var script2 = document.createElement("script");
script2.innerHTML = "window.FB = null;FB=null;";
head.appendChild(script2);
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me too, however I'd recommend getting a little more jQuery-ish with something like `$("head").append("<script>window.FB=null;FB=null;</script>")`. Just a thought

Answer (score 2):

Although, the code provided by Loic Devaux will do the trick it is not needed in your case. He is solving an issue with markup shown on a third party website...

I had the same problem and initially added this code to solve it. Then I thought that there must be something wrong and I wasn't doing the things right. I added facebook comment box to a page that already had a facebook share button. So I just moved the share script after the initialization script and the error disappeared.

My advice is to check whether you have more than one FB widget on your page(s). If so read the documentation and make sure you've added the correct scripts on the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

Loic's solution does not work in IE. Instead you have to do this:

```
var head = $("head").get(0);  // using jquery
var script2 = document.createElement("script");
if (!$.browser.msie ) {
    script2.innerHTML = "window.FB = null;FB=null;";
}else{
    script2.text = "window.FB = null;FB=null;";
}
head.appendChild(script2);
```