# CakePHP Facebook plugin (webtechnick) only 'share' working

Tags: facebook, cakephp, plugins

I'm trying to use the Facebook plugin from webtechnick with my CakePHP 1.3.10 app. I've followed all the directions to install it and have all the functionalities available:

- Downloaded package and installed in **app/plugins/facebook**
- Created **app/config/facebook.php** with my app's id, key and secret numbers, based on the example config file
- Included **$helpers = array('Facebook.Facebook')** in my **app_controller.php**
- Echoed the **$this->Facebook->html()** function in my layout (replcing the default html tag)
- Echoed the **$this->Facebook->init()** function at the bottom of the layout, before

Then, I use this code in my view:

```
echo $this->Facebook->share('link'); 
echo $this->Facebook->like();   
echo $this->Facebook->comments();
```

But I only get the share button, not the like or comments. Am I missing any step? If I **echo** something inside the facebook helper **like()** function for example, it prints in in the view, so it's actually calling the function, but not generating the facbook element. Any ideas? I don't know what else to try, I believe I've followed all the steps...

**----------UPDATE--------------------------**

With Firebug I see this script error: **FB.provide** is not a function

The file where the error comes from is **http://connect.facebook.net/es_ES/all.js**, which I assume the plugin calls it. But since it's in Facebook's servers, what can I do about it? Does that mean there's a problem on their end? I don't see many more things I can do in my end. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It appears the all.js file causes problems in both IE and Firefox. I'm using IE8 and Firefox 7.

After looking at the following...[Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110991/facebook-like-uncaught-typeerror-object-an-object-has-no-method-provide) and [Facebook Bug Report](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=19042) I was able to solve both. The fix for me was editing the facebook.php helper and adding the following...

**IE Fix**

```
FB.UIServer.setActiveNode = function(a,b){FB.UIServer._active[a.id]=b;}
```

**Firefox Fix**

```
window.FB = null;
FB = null;
```

**Complete init() function**

```
function init($options = array()){
    if(FacebookInfo::getConfig('appId')){
        $appId = FacebookInfo::getConfig('appId');
        $session = json_encode($this->Session->read('FB.Session'));
        $init = '<div id="fb-root"></div>';
        $init .=  $this->Html->scriptBlock(
            "
            window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                FB.init({
                    appId   : '{$appId}',
                    session : {$session}, // don't refetch the session when PHP already has it
                    status  : true, // check login status
                    cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                    xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
                });

                /* IE FIX */
                FB.UIServer.setActiveNode = function(a,b){FB.UIServer._active[a.id]=b;}
                /**********/

                // whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function() {
                    window.location.reload();
                });
            };
            (function() {

                /* FIREFOX FIX */
                window.FB = null;
                FB = null;
                /**********/

                var e = document.createElement('script');
                e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/{$this->locale}/all.js';
                e.async = true;
                document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
            }());
            ",
            $options
        );
        return $init;
    }
    else {
        return "<span class='error'>No Facebook configuration detected. Please add the facebook configuration file to your config folder.</span>";
    } 
}
```

A little late but I hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

This may be due to the fact that Facebook deprecating FBML.

So use the normal `html` tag instead of `$this->Facebook->html();` before the `HEAD` tag.

This works for me. Btw, it's becoming a pain to develop for Facebook lol. Cheers to being a developer, I think we will die young. >.<

> > "On Jan 1, 2012: FBML will no longer be supported on Platform. June 1, 2012: FBML apps will no longer work. " Read more about it here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/

Answer (score 1):

Put facebook directory into the app/plugins directory and put facebook.php from config folder of facebook directory into app/config folder and I am sure your problem will get solve immediately.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- Go to: https://developers.facebook.com/apps then create new app.
- In the "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" section: Tick website and input your site url.
- Copy /plugin/Facebook/config/facebook.php.example to app/config/facebook.php , open facebook.php and modify your app id and your secret.
  That's all.